# Why the following stochastic inequality is valid

Tags: stochastic-processes, martingales, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis

Consider a Banach space-valued dyadic martingale $M_n$ on $\Omega=\{-1,1\}^{\mathbb N_*}$ associated with to $\mathcal{A}=\sigma(\epsilon_1,\epsilon_2,\cdots,\epsilon_n)$, where $\epsilon_n:\Omega\to \{-1,1\}$ denotes the $n$-th coordinate. Also, let us write martingale difference $dM_n:=M_n-M_{n-1}$.  Therefore, by Representation of Paley–Walsh martingales it follows that there exists a $\mathcal{A}_{n-1}$-measurable function $\delta_{n-1}$ such that
$$
dM_n=\delta_{n-1}\epsilon_n. 
$$
In a paper, it claim that for any $q\in (2,\infty)$, the following inequality is valid
$$
\int_{\Omega\times \Omega}|M_{n-1}(\omega)+\epsilon_n(\omega')\delta_{n-1}(\omega)|^q dP(\omega')dP(\omega)\leq \int_{\Omega}|M_n(\omega)|^qdP(\omega)
$$
Why ?

Comment: What is $P$?$\ $

Comment: Do we know anything about the $\epsilon$'s, e.g. are they independent?  The claim follows if $M_{n}=M_{n-1}(\omega)+\epsilon_n(\omega)\delta_{n-1}(\omega)$ is a mean preserving spread of $M_{n-1}(\omega)+\epsilon_n(\omega')\delta_{n-1}(\omega)$, which is determined by how $\epsilon_n$ and $\delta_{n-1}$ are related  conditional on $M_{n-1}$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins I assume $P$ is the probability measure.

Comment: @JohnDawkins The probability measure

Comment: @SherwinLott Yes, $\epsilon$ is independent

Comment: I'm a bit confused then as to why it's not just equal?  If $\epsilon_n(\omega)$ is independent, then so is $\epsilon_n(\omega')$, and it shouldn't matter which you use?  Maybe linking the paper would help me understand.

Comment: @SherwinLott It may be equal.